# Redirecting after iframe submission

Tags: php, redirect, iframe, forwarding

Is there anyway to redirect after an iframe form is completed, even though i am not hosting the form itself.

I want to send users to a thank you page but the form is an iframe so i have no control over the code in the iframe itself.

Comment: nothing i figured since i cant edit the iframe code and i'm not hosting it, that this wasnt possible but was just asking

Comment: why would you make a thank you page for a form you're not hosting ?...

Comment: tracking and optimizing keywords and submissions

Comment: have a look at this: http://roneiv.wordpress.com/2008/01/18/get-the-content-of-an-iframe-in-javascript-crossbrowser-solution-for-both-ie-and-firefox/ . Perhaps you can bind an event to the form inside the iframe or if that sort of cross domain access is not possible at least you can determine when the form has been submitted successfully based on the content of the iframe when it changes. Like searching for a string that indicates successful submission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hook the `onload` event of the IFRAME. On the first load (the form is loaded) do nothing. On the second load (the form is submitted and its result displayed) do a client-side redirect via `location.href`